# Adding Item in ListBox with different FONT c#

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to add some item in ListBox with different font that I specify at runtime in somewhere in code

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for you

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/dacea8cd-963e-4a40-9af6-1495acf1d3c5